# Software timers using hardware interrupt

Tags: timer

I have to implement a counter for upto 30 minutes on my microcontroller. However the hardware interrupts maximum time is nowhere close to this. So I think I would be using the interrupt and increment a variable everytime the interrupt is called by the hardware. However I would like to know if there are already any such open source timers available which I can port and use more easily rather than writing evertything from scratch. The second question is :

```
interrupt timer()
{
/increment a count

}
```

Other than setting a flag when my required counter value is reached is there any more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize a variable in the global scope, and then have your timer interrupt increment it and check the value. Its literally four lines of code.

Comment: I agree. It was just that I wasnt sure if this was the way it  is generally done since polling it from the main loop may not be very efficient.

Comment: @user43914 done all the time. The addition and comparison is very minimal codewise, only takes a few clock cycles.

Comment: @user43914 - Don't forget to declare the variable `volatile`, so checks don't get compiled out.